# Ruby OptionParser throwing ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, optionparser

this is my first time using OptionParser and i'm getting this error:

> /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-> 2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:651:in `resolve': absolute URL needed (not -v) (ArgumentError)from /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:223:in`fetch'
>       from /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:440:in `get'
>       from /Users/jay/Code/linkedin-scraper/lib/myModel-scraper/profile.rb:20:in`initialize'
>       from ./bin/myModel-scraper:6:in `new'
>       from ./bin/myModel-scraper:6:in`'

Bin:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'optparse'

opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|
 opts.on_tail("-v", "--version", "Show version") { puts myModel::Scraper::VERSION; exit }
 opts.parse!
end
```

Lib/version:

```
module myModel
  module Scraper
    VERSION = '0.1.2'
  end
end
```

I guess i'm doing this completely wrong, could somebody explain whats happening here?

Comment: What command are you using to invoke the script? Does it work if you pull the `opts.parse!` outside of the block?

Comment: Your error is coming from mechanize, not OptionParser.

Comment: I'm trying to use `mymodel-scraper -v`.  My lib class is `mymodel-scraper.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd usually write an OptionParser block like this:

```
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on_tail("-v", "--version", "Show version") { puts myModel::Scraper::VERSION; exit }
end.parse!
```

I'd probably use `on` instead of `on_tail`:

```
opts.on("-v", "--version", "Show version") { puts myModel::Scraper::VERSION; exit }
```

but I understand why you might want it to appear at the end of the help list.